# Ruby on Rails 5 random NameError: uninitialized constant on namespaced models in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have this two namespaced models in the **app/models/admin** folder:

**transactiontype.rb :**

```
module Admin
  class TransactionType < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "transactiontypes"

    has_many :transactions
  end
end
```

**transaction.rb :**

```
module Admin
  class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "transactions"

    belongs_to :transactiontype
  end
end
```

Inside **schema.rb**, table definitions look like this:

```
  create_table "transactiontypes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description", limit: 30, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description", limit: 30, null: false
    t.bigint "transactiontype_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

add_foreign_key "transactions", "transactiontypes"
```

Now if I open the rails console and type:

**Admin::TransactionType.all**

I get this error:

**NameError: uninitialized constant Admin::TransactionType**

Weird thing is, I've been opening and closing the console for the past hour, sometimes it worked without error (showing the correct "SELECT" in the console), sometimes it got the NameError message. I then issued a **rails restart** command and since then, I got the NameError al the time.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: class Admin::TransactionType < ApplicationRecord
    
end 

Will work

Comment: sovalina's answer did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Naming Convention](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions), you create your table `transactiontypes` without underscore.

So Rails try to find in your db the model `Admin::Transactiontype` and not `Admin::TransactionType`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the class name in the model to Transactiontype (no Camel Case) and it worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check your schema.rb, here model name is `transactiontypes` and `transactions`. So you don't need to add `self.table_name = "transactiontypes"` and `self.table_name = "transactions"` on `transactiontypes.rb` and `transactions.rb`. Rather than this just change **app/models/admin** folder:

**transactiontype.rb :**

```
module Admin
  class Transactiontype < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :transactions
  end
end
```

**transaction.rb :**

```
module Admin
  class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :transactiontype
  end
end
```

Now you can try on rails console:

```
Admin::Transactiontype.all
```